# Does anyone know how to display TIFF images stored in a SQL table in .ASP classic page?

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I can get it to work in IE 11 but not Chrome or Edge.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/tiff" 

response.binarywrite objrs("imagedata")
```

Comment: Ah yes.  Not what I wanted the answer to be but looks like the correct one.  Thank you for the link!

Comment: That's often how it goes.